# Can Updates Be Installed When Booting Desktop from a Live-USB?

Tags: updates, dell, live-usb, boot-repair, inspiron

My new Dell Inspiron 15-3552 laptop (which came with 14.04 pre-installed) has an unstable desktop after I tried a general software update which froze part-way through.  I tried to generate a Boot-Info report using the alternative method with a Boot-Repair-Disk live-USB I made but haven't been able to get to the Boot Repair window, only a desktop. Using the standard method and the orange Canonical Store 16.04 live-USB I get to the 16.04 desktop ok but the second Terminal command (to install) fails.  As a test I tried updating Calculator and Calendar but these failed as well.  I made my own 16.04 live-USB and tried updating Calculator from the desktop booted from this - that failed as well, hence my question.  I'm using the Try Ubuntu options as I want to preserve the contents of the laptop's HDD for investigation/repair.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to the question in the title is yes, if your Ubuntu system is healthy.

You can install new program packages, and you can update and upgrade program packages. Don't try to update and upgrade everything. You might fill the RAM drive, where the file system is located, and make the system crash.

But - and an important but - all these installed programs will be lost after shutdown or reboot.

---

If you want your changes to survive alias persist after shutdown or reboot, you can make a **persistent live** Ubuntu system. Then there will be a file or partition named/labeled **casper-rw**, where your new program packages and also created personal files and tweaks are stored. See these links,

[help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb)

[mkusb/persistent](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb/persistent)

Comment: Thanks for the answer - that's what I would have expected.  Obviously the 14.04 installed on the HDD is now unhealthy but I would have thought booting from a freshly-made 16.04 live-USB should mean I have a healthy system running in Ram and should then be able to upgrade, for example, just Calculator.  I'll try a few more times and also make a 14.04 live-USB and try that.  Of course, all I'm trying to do is create a Boot-Info report as @DavidFoerster suggested in response to a related question.

Comment: Please use the first point release, 16.04.1 LTS. It is debugged and polished, much better than the original 16.04 LTS. But there might be other problems, for example with drivers. So if 14.04 is working well, you should try that version, also in this case 14.04.1 LTS with the trusty kernel (same kernel series as the original 14.04 but updated) which is better than the original one. There is also 14.04.5 LTS, the fifth point release with the xenial kernel.

Comment: Thanks @sudodus. Thought I'd check which point release of 14.04 Dell installed. Booting from the HDD I get an "An error occurred while mounting /boot/efi." message. I can skip mounting to get to a flaky desktop with a "System program problem detected" window. It can't find any wireless networks but the desktop is sort-of usable although windows keep changing slightly and the mouse cursor keeps disappearing. Just "ubuntu 14.04 LTS" is indicated under the Ubuntu/Dell/Energy Star logos in Help/All Settings/Details/Overview so how can I check the point release please?

Comment: `lsb_release -a` but also `uname -a` , which will display the kernel, the 3.13 series is the 'trusty kernel', the 4.4 series is the 'xenial kernel'.

Comment: Thanks @sudodus - will check later.  Good news, though - I've just stumbled across a factory OS-restore option detailed in another question I just posted.

Comment: Dell installed 14.04.5 LTS, 3.13 kernel on this laptop.  I was able to get a Boot-Info report with the standard method by booting from a 14.04 live-USB and will post a separate question with the link to it.  I tried again using the 16.04 live-USB but step 1 of the standard method errored on the first try, ok on the second, but step 2 failed as before.

Comment: Good luck with 14.04 and the 3.13 kernel :-)